# Delete a broken postgreSQL table

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, debian

I have a table of ~20 millions in postgreSQL and I want to delete it.

But every one of there operations doesn't work (It still running more than 12 hours without success):

```
- DELETE
- TRUNCATE
- VACUUM
- ANALYZE
```

I can't do anythink on this table...

A few day's ago I try to re-generate the id (BIGSERIAL) of each line with:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE "data_id_seq" RESTART WITH 1
UPDATE data SET id=nextval('data_id_seq')
```

And I think this operation brok the table...

If someone know how can I delete this table, thanks for help !

Comment: delete from thattable limit 10 can't work (syntax error at or near "limit"). The table is not indexed. As i said, vaccum doesn't work (infinite loading)

Comment: try like this `DELETE FROM thattable
WHERE ctid IN (
    SELECT ctid
    FROM thattable
    LIMIT 10
)`

Comment: Are there any other connections? Something else might have a lock on the table.

Comment: check your `server status`(an option available in `pgAdmin`) to know whether that table is locked or something like that

Comment: and `re-index`, `vaccum` that table

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
DROP TABLE table_name;
```

[See the doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-droptable.html)

Comment: same think, infinite loading

Comment: Try the CASCADE after your table name.
For ex.  DROP TABLE table_name CASCADE;